# Can we get statistics from Bing search?

Tags: bing

I want to setup Bing search for my own website with the help of [Bing API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search). Is it possible to get some sort of statistics that tells me what kind of searches users made on my website or where they are coming from, etc? Is there any feature available in Bing that give me these kind or any other kind of statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing provides statistics that includes call volume, top queries, user agent, response code, amongst other things on https://bingapistatistics.com.

Bing Statistics is not available for standalone API offerings at the moment:

> Bing Statistics Add-in is only available with the Bing APIs' Tiers S1 to S9. It is not available for the standalone API offerings. However, Bing Statistics does provide metrics for all the endpoints included in various Tiers. It is also not available for any other APIs on Cognitive Services apart from the Bing APIs (through S1 to S9 Tiers).

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/web/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Bing Web Search API does NOT offer analytics for the searched terms, duration, etc.

As a workaround, one can integrate the Bing Web Search API with the free **Site Search Tracking** offered by **Google Analytics**.

To set this up follow the official guidelines:

> Sign in to your Analytics account.
>
> Click Admin, and navigate to the view in which you want to set up Site Search.
>
> Click View Settings.
>
> Under Site Search Settings, set Site Search Tracking to ON.
>
> In the Query Parameter field, enter the word or words that designate internal query parameters, such as term,search,query. Sometimes query parameters are designated by just a letter, such as s or q. Enter up to five parameters, separated by commas. Do not enter any additional characters: for example, if the query parameter is designated by the letter q, enter only q (not q=).

Reference:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

Please note, Microsoft Bing does offer:

- API calls monitoring via the Azure Portal (however it's not possible to see anything about the search terms for instance)
- Search Keywords via the Bing Webmaster site (however this data seems to come from the general Bing.com search engine itself)